# Creating FULLTEXT field within Schema migration

Tags: laravel, schema

I'm making a Laravel package primarily for internal project use at the minute but I've hit a bit of a snag...

I'm adding a `searchable` fulltext column to each model that is needed to be searched. I'm using Laravel's native migration features like so -

```php
Schema::table('assets', function (Blueprint $table) {
    Searchable::migrateUp($table, 'moderated');
});
```

So that calls a method to deploy the migration after the `moderated` column. Here's what that method looks like -

```php
public function migrateUp(Blueprint $table, $after = null)
{

    // add our searchable column
    $table
        ->longText('searchable')
        ->after($after)->nullable();

    // ToDo: get indexing working on migration
    // add a fulltext index
    DB::statement(
        'ALTER TABLE ? ADD FULLTEXT fulltext_searchable (?)',
        [$table->getTable(), 'searchable']
    );

    // return our table
    return $table;
}
```

So a nullable long text field is created and then I am trying to create a FULLTEXT index from that. The problem being of course at the point I'm running my statement, the searchable column doesn't actually exist yet. Is there any way I can do this while it still being as simple as the user calling `Searchable::migrateUp()` within their migration file?

Appreciate any pointers! Chris.

Comment: check if this helps - https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/general-discussion/fulltext-indexes-at-migrations

Comment: @samo unfortunately not - they all seem to suggest you have to run this outside of the Schema::table() method

Comment: You stated you are using "Laravel's native migration" but quickly took a diverge off that path by making your own method which uses the DB raw class. Instead, use the ORM interfaces Schema classes methods: https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/migrations#creating-columns

Comment: @developernator - I am using Laravel's schema to create the column in the first place - where I am having trouble is creating a FULLTEXT index inside the Schema callback.

Comment: Can't `migrateUp()` accept the table name as the first parameter and then call `Schema::table($table, function (Blueprint $table) {[...});` itself?

Comment: @JonasStaudenmeir - brilliant suggestion. I don't know why I didn't think of that! You know when you're just overlooking the simple solution for the complex one?!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I was code blind when coming up with this - you know when you can't see past the overly complex solution for the simple one?! Slight change of mindset and refactoring thanks to @JonasStaudenmeir and my solution is as follows -

My migrations -

```
 /**
 * Run the migrations.
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function up()
{
    Searchable::migrateUp('assets', 'moderated');

}

/**
 * Reverse the migrations.
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function down()
{
    Searchable::migrateDown('assets');
}
```

My methods -

```
 /**
 * Creates searchable column on model table
 *
 * @param string      $table Table name to perform migration on
 * @param string|null $after Whether to add after a particular column
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function migrateUp($table, $after = null)
{

    // add to our schema
    Schema::table(
        $table,
        function (Blueprint $table) use ($after) {
            $table->longText($this->_searchableColumnKey)
                ->after($after)->nullable();
        }
    );

    // create our index
    \DB::statement("ALTER TABLE {$table} ADD FULLTEXT fulltext_searchable ({$this->_searchableColumnKey})");
}

/**
 * Removes searchable column on table
 *
 * @param Blueprint $table Requires blueprint
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function migrateDown($table)
{
    Schema::table(
        $table,
        function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->dropColumn($this->_searchableColumnKey);
        }
    );
}
```

So rather than my methods being called by Schema, I simply run the schema from within the methods instead!